# Не могу считать числа из файла Java

Tags: scanner

Нужно считать числа из файла используя FileInputStream и записать их в ArrayList. При запуске моего кода выдает ошибку java.util.NoSuchElementException. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
    try {
        fileName = reader.readLine();
       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
        int i ;
        while ((i= scanner.nextInt()) != -1){
            list.add(i);

        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Файл не найден");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Что-то пошло не так");
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null){
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Глупая ошибка.

```
    try {
        fileName = reader.readLine();
       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
        int i;
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            i = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(i);

        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Файл не найден");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Что-то пошло не так");
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null){
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```